# is it possible to update entity with out setters being called in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am working on application, which has an entity called My.java, it is extending from another entity which has field called edited.
This field will be updated with current time stamp, for each update

I am using single table inheritance strategy.

I am using jpa/eclipse link as persistance provider.

edited field is updating with current time stamp even with out setter method called, there are no other references in my java code changing the value of this edited field.

While debugging I can see  UPDATE QL statement, for edited field update.

I am really wondering why/how it's value updating, it it possible with out setter invocation?

Here is the mapped super class:

```
  @MappedSuperclass

public abstract class SuperEntity implements  Serializable {    

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1125783654888232605L;
/**
 * The time the entry was created
 */
@Column(name = "CREATED")
private Timestamp created;
/**
 * The date the entry was edited
 */
@Column(name = "EDITED")
@Version
private Timestamp edited;
```

Comment: It could be using annotations. Are there any annotations on the `edited` field in the entity?  e.g. `@UpdateTimestamp`.  Or are there any methods in the entity that have annotations such as `@PrePersist`?  Posting both your entity classes would help.

Comment: have posted the java class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these things.

1. Your entity may be implementing some kind of auditable interface
2. Your field may be having @Version annotation

In 1st case you have figure out that interface usage and you can understand it
In 2nd case it's the default and expected behavior in EJB and Hibernate.

I got this link after googling it may be useful for you

https://technology.amis.nl/2006/01/03/ejb-30-persistence-using-the-version-annotation-for-optimistic-locking-in-the-glassfish-reference-implementation/

It's not a big worry thing, you can get over it easily

Answer (score 1):

Yes. JPA implementations don't need some property listener or proxy for your class to detect that a value has been updated via a setter. How they detect changes to a managed instance can be implementation-dependent, but updates to a field via direct access instead of a getter/setter is supported. For example, a copy of an instance obtained via the persistence manager can be kept, and on completing a transaction or when a commit is issued, the managed instances you might have made changes to are compared with their originals and updates to the database issued as necessary.

In fact, it is possible to explicitly specify how access to an entity class will be performed, through this annotation: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Access.html

Conversly, there might be properties that aren't backed by a field, but instead have a getter that computes a value. When using property access, those too would result in generating columns when creating a database from your code, and inserting/updating values when persisting or merging the entity.

So in short, just calling the setter isn't what flags a property or persisted field in a managed entity as "dirty". If you can directly access a field and change it, that too results in an update.

Answer (score 1):

A field with a `@Version` annotation on it will be automatically controlled by hibernate, and used for its [optimistic locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) functionality.

So Hibernate itself is automatically setting that field when you save the entity.

Comment: Suggest you replace Hibernate with EclipseLink in your answer, since he says "I am using EclipseLink"